# import theano gets Illegal instruction

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04, theano

after install the bleeding-edge version and even uninstall Theano, I'm still getting "Illegal instruction" from "import theano", i'm on ubuntu 12.04 precise

```
zhge@phx-r-ins1-7773:~$ sudo pip uninstall Theano
Uninstalling Theano:
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled Theano
zhge@phx-r-ins1-7773:~$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import theano
Illegal instruction
zhge@phx-r-ins1-7773:~$
```

Answer (score 6):

This can happen when you move from one computer to another with the same `.local` directory. The following (from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/T0521GHRC1w)) worked for me:

First delete `~/.theano` which stores some theano compiled files. Then reinstall theano via `pip uninstall theano; pip install --user theano`. It also fixes the gensim install for some reason (which shows the same error upon importing). Perhaps gensim imports theano when it can?

Comment: How can i use Theano with the same .local directory in 2 different computers?